# how to register for a Packet-in-message change-event-notfication?

Tags: sdn, opendaylight, openflow

I am trying to get a notification (over REST connection) when any host is trying to communicate in my network.  I registered for a Packet-in-message change-event-notification that I found in the packet-processing module. when I start listening using my websocket client, I receive nothing!!!!!

I was expecting some notification with each packet-in reaching the controller. am I miss-understanding the use of this module? what is the purpose of this packet-in-message? 
Is there a way to get a notification when any host is trying to set a communication with another host (over REST)?

I built my topology in mininet. It contains some openflow switches and hosts. The Opendaylight controller has l2switching, restconf, openflowplugin and dlux features enabled.

Comment: What do you mean by host? Do you mean OVS switch?

Comment: Mininet Hosts, or servers. Not OVS switches.